# How to check multiple input boxes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Updated.

On my shopping cart page there is an update button which I want to check all the items in the cart to see if they have more than 1 and not 0 - all the input boxes look like this:

```
Apple £4
<input type="text" size="3" value="1" name="quantity[50:YToyOntpOjIyNztzOjI6IjE3IjtpOjIyODtzOjI6IjIxIjt9]">

Orange £6
<input type="text" size="3" value="1" name="quantity[50:YToyOntpOjIyNztzOjI6IjE3IjtpOjIyODtzOjI6IjIewrew]">
```

I have decided to use a nested .css class rather than name as that is always unique.

```
var errorQty=0;
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var errorQty=0;
    // this is an input box, more than one on the page
    var QtyItems = $('#ShopTable tbody tr td input');

    if(QtyItems=="0" || QtyItems=="1") {
        QtyItems.addClass("errorform");
        errorQty=1;
    } else {
        QtyItems.removeClass("errorform");
    }

    if (errorQty==1){
    } else {    
        $('#updateOrder').click(function () {       
            $('#updateOrderLoader').slideDown("fast");
            document.basket.submit();
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

This is my button. I want the code to work only on click of this button not on load!

```
<a href="#updateOrder" id="updateOrder" title="Update Cart"><img src="//cdn.com/cart/btnUpdate.png" alt="Update Cart" title="Update Cart"/></a>
```

Comment: First of all, before starting on a solution, $('#.table.ShopTable tbody tr td input'); should be $('table.ShopTable tbody tr td input');
or table#ShopTable if that's the ID.

Comment: Secondly, `id`s must be unique (submitQty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$('#updateOrder').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var errorQty=0;
    var QtyItems = $('table.ShopTable tbody tr td input');
    $.each(QtyItems, function(){
        var _this = $(this);
        if(_this.val()=="0" || _this.val()=="1") {
            _this.addClass("errorform");
            errorQty=1;
         } else {
             _this.removeClass("errorform");
         }
    });
    if (errorQty==0){
         $('#updateOrderLoader').slideDown("fast");
         document.basket.submit();
         return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list of input elements:

```
$('#.table.ShopTable tbody tr td input')
    .each(function(idx, el) {
              if (el.val() == '1' || el.val() == '0') {
                 el.addClass("errorform");
                 ...
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

## Button

```
<a onclick="goUpdate()" href="#updateOrder"><img src="//cdn.com/cart/btnUpdate.png"/></a>
```

## jQuery

```
var form_flag = 0;

function goUpdate() {

    var Items = $("#submitQty");

    if ($(Items).val() == "" || $(Items).val() == "1" || $(Items).val() == "0") {
        $(Items).addClass("errorform");
        form_flag = 1;
    } else {
        $(Items).removeClass("errorform");
    }
    // ALL INFORMATION GOOD ..
    if (form_flag == 1) {
        // NULL CANNOT SUBMIT
    } else {
        var cartForm;
        cartForm = document.getElementById("basket"); // enter the ID or Name or class of your form
        cartForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not check for ALL the items. It only checks the first item??

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors in your code:

1) `$('#.table.ShopTable tbody tr td input');` should be `$('table.ShopTable tbody tr td input');`

2) Here `if (errorQty=1){` should be `if (errorQty == 1){`

3) The control is empty, so you can do:

```
if (errorQty != 1){ // if errorQty is not 1.
```

Then wrap everything inside the button action:

```
$('#updateOrder').on('click', function() {

    ...

});
```

and it work.